# How to make FOR run together with while?

Tags: python, selenium, indentation

I have the code below working until the WHILE, I needed to add the WHILE to capture all the information on the page.

However, when the code stops working, I need to know how I can make the code run after the While.

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument('--disable-notifications')

webdriver_service = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=webdriver_service)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 1)

url =     "https://www.google.com.br/maps/search/contabilidade+balneario+camboriu/@-26.9905418,-48.6289914,1    5z"
driver.get(url)
while True:
    try:
        wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,     "//span[contains(text(),'reached the end')]")))
        barraRolagem = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,     "//div[@role='main']//div[@aria-label]")))
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scroll(0, arguments[0].scrollHeight);",     barraRolagem)
        break
    except:
        barraRolagem = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,     "//div[@role='main']//div[@aria-label]")))
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scroll(0, arguments[0].scrollHeight);",     barraRolagem)
    time.sleep(0.5)

    classe_empresas = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "hfpxzc")

    for empresa in classe_empresas:
          urls = empresa.get_attribute("href")
          links.append(urls)


  for paginas_individuais in links:
        driver.get(paginas_individuais)  
              
        try:
              print("Telefone")
              tel = driver.find_element(By. XPATH, "//div[contains(text(),'("+ddd+")')]").get_attribute("innerHTML")
              print("Endereco")
              endereco = driver.find_element(By. XPATH, "/html[1]/body[1]/div[3]/div[9]/div[9]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[7]/div[3]/button[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]").get_attribute("innerHTML")                  
              print("Nome")
              nome = driver.find_element(By. TAG_NAME, "title").get_attribute("innerHTML")

       except:
              print("erro")
```

Comment: According to presented here code `for paginas_individuais in links:` appears with indentation. This may cause problems...

Comment: Ok, I corrected the indentations and it worked thanks

Comment: OK, I posted the answer. maybe this can be useful for future users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for paginas_individuais in links:` block not worked due to unintended indentation.
This block should be with the same indentation as `while True:` block to make it performed after the `while True:` block is completed.